# How to click a button created using <span> tag for Selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have span tag which looks like a button on html tag

```
    <span class="middle">Next</span>
```

I tried using

```
    xpath=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='modal-actions-panel']/div[2]/a/span/span/span")); // by considering fixed id as reference
```

Using absolute

```
xpath=driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div[2]/a/span/span/span"));  // took this from firebug
```

and Using

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[class='middle']"));
```

No success!! It is throwing below exception :

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(., \"Next\")]"}
>       Command duration or timeout: 30.12 seconds
>       For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

For all the ways I tried it is showing the same exception with change in selector details. Can someone please help me out in finding solution so that I can find Next button that is in span tag and click it.

Next button is in iFrame: Below is the part of html covering required span tag.

Next

I also tried with :

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe-applicationname_ModalDialog_0");
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.middle"));
```

But throwing below error :

> Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

Kindly let me know if needed something that I'm missing..

Comment: The CSS selector looks right. To verify xpath: Open the page manually with firefox. Press F12 to open dev tools and switch to console. Type `$x("//span[@class='middle']").length` to see how many elements are matched by that Xpath. If Selenium fails to find it, you may be looking at the wrong window or frame.

Comment: I can see the count as 0. But when I right click on Next button and inspect element, I can just see <span class="middle">Next</span> and xpath(s) as mentioned above. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you look for frame or iframe?? May this element is inside any frame or iframe?? Verify it..

Comment: can you post the exact HTML code?

Comment: Adding just a required part of html,<iframe id="iframe-applicationname_ModalDialog_0" class="iframe-applicationname_ModalDialog_0  applicationname_ModalDialog_0
-active-modalapplicationname" frameborder="0" title="Modal Frame - Register Person" iscpiframe="false" data-dojo-attach-point="frame" allowtransparency="true"visibility: visible;">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<span class="middle">Next</span>
</head>
</html>
</iframe>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this element is inside a frame or iframe, if it is then you need to switch that frame or iframe before finding element as below :-

```
driver.switchTo().frame("iframe-applicationname_ModalDialog_0");
WebElement el = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.middle"));
el.click();

//Now after all your stuff done inside frame need to switch to default content 
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

**Edited1** :- If you are getting exception as element is not currently visible need to implement `WebDriverWait` to wait until element visible as below :-

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

//Find frame or iframe and switch
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("iframe-applicationname_ModalDialog_0"));

//Now find the element 
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//span[@class = 'middle' and contains(text(), 'Next')]")));
el.click();

//Once all your stuff done with this frame need to switch back to default
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

**Edited2** :- If unfortunately it's not getting visible try to click on it using `JavascriptExecutor` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

//Find frame or iframe and switch
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt("iframe-applicationname_ModalDialog_0"));

//Now find the element 
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//span[@class = 'middle' and contains(text(), 'Next')]")));

//Now click using JavascriptExecutor
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click()" el); 

//Once all your stuff done with this frame need to switch back to default
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this....

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'middle') and contains(text(), 'Next')]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

span is like button, it is also clickable, if you can't click then your xpath is wrong, or it is capturing many spans !

- right click on mouse, inspect, go to console tab
- type: **$x("your xpath here");**
- finally see how many outputs, it will also tell if your xpath has an error

Answer (score -1):

I tried it and it worked for me:

```
WebElement actionBtn=driver2.findElement(
  By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'v-menubar-menuitem-caption')
  and contains(text(), 'Actions')]")
);
actionBtn.click();
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'middle') and contains(text(), 'Next')]"))).click();
```